# Javascript DOM elements hide class and the element not present are same?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am currently working on a project where most of the code has been written by someone else . I was supposed to do some slight modifications in the existing script to incorporate changes in a new file. I came across a situation where it was very confusing . The scenario is as cited below:

I have an element named as `complextabs` and it is being used for almost all the pages, except for the one which is being created newly. The situation is there is a code snippet that is written as `$('.complextabs').hasClass('.hide')`. this incredibly returns the same as when the element `complextabs` is not even present in the page. Can someone please throw some light on this

And yeah, I am working on `Backbone.js` . Has this got something to do with the use of `Backbone.js`

Any suggestion and advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Explain it fully and share code what you want and what is not working.

Comment: This is a direct Jquery statement and not related to Backbone.js. Anyways, share the code to identify the issue.

Comment: It should be `$('.complextabs').hasClass('hide')`, not `$('.complextabs').hasClass('.hide')`.

Comment: David Knipe - Sorry , that was a typo error :)

Comment: Guys , its very difficult to share the entire code as it is spread across the entire application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that has nothing to do with the use of Backbone.

Consider the following:

```
$('.asdasda').hasClass('hide')
```

This will return false, and it *should* return false because `$('.asdasda')` does not return any results. Just running that will yield a JQuery wrapper over an empty list and since there are no elements then obviously there's nothing in there with the css class `hide`.

If you want to check that there is an element with both the `complextabs` and the `hide` class then use `$('.complextabs.hide').length`.

Comment: @ivarni- yes, you are correct on that . I even did $('.complextabs.hide').length. and $('.complextabs').length. The irony is that although the element is not present in DOM , yet , it returns true when i use the condition if(!$('.complextabs').hasClass('.hide')), irrespective of whether the element is present in the DOM or not

Comment: @RitumoniSharma Well, since we already established that `$('.complextabs').hasClass('.hide')` will return `false` when the element is not in the DOM then you're basically doing `if(!false)` :)

Comment: yeah...correct . its like equating 0 with nothing  :). Thanks a lot. got it :)